# React - component state not being set

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web

Why is the output of the piece of code below "true"?

```
class InstagramGallery extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            images: true
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        var accessToken = '*Instagram token*';
        var instagramApi = new Instagram(accessToken);
        instagramApi.userSelfMedia().then(function(result) {
            this.setState({
                images: false,
            });
        }, function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        });

    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.state.images); 
        return (
            <div className="instagram-gallery">

            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

From what I know, the constructor is being called first. Therefore `images=true`, after that it renders with `console.log(true)`, and `componentDidMount` is called. After data from instagram is fetched, and I update component state which should re-render the component with `images=false`. Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using a regular function for `instagramAp.userSelfMedia` callback hence losing `this` context. Use an arrow function instead:

```
instagramApi.userSelfMedia().then(
  result => {
    this.setState({
      images: false
    });
  },
  function(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
);
```

Regular functions create their own lexical scope, so `this` does not point your class in the callback function. Arrow functions don't create their own lexical scopes, to `this` points your component and you can use `this.setState()`.

Using an arrow function saves you from binding your function or keeping `this` in another variable like:

```
var accessToken = "*Instagram token*";
var instagramApi = new Instagram(accessToken);
const that = this;
instagramApi.userSelfMedia().then(
  function(result) {
    that.setState({
      images: false
    });
  },
  function(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
);
```

Answer (score 2):

I've not been using RN for that long but does this have an affect?

```
componentDidMount() {
    var accessToken = '*Instagram token*';
    var instagramApi = new Instagram(accessToken);
    instagramApi.userSelfMedia().then((result) => { //USING ARROW FUNCTION
        this.setState({
            images: false,
        });
    }, function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    });

}
```

I added an arrow function so that the 'this.state' doesn't get mixed up with the 'this' inside instagramApi.userSelfMedia().

Answer (score 2):

Because this isn’t available

Use arrow function

```
 instagramApi.userSelfMedia().then((result) => {
        this.setState({
            images: false,
        });
    }, function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    });

  }
```

Or bind it manually

```
  instagramApi.userSelfMedia().then(function(result) {
        this.setState({
            images: false,
        });
    }.bind(this), function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    });

  }
```